# Product name in code on the mini cart

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

First thanks for this persones who will take the time to help me.
Here is my problem, i bought a plugin for woocommerce who calls composit product. When I create a product all works correctly, but when i add the product to the mini-cart it appear the name of the products kits in code. Look at the picture.
[image: Codes who apear]

I found the codes in this two php pages but i think something is going wrong here but i don't know where :

This is the component file :

```js
    <?php
/**
 * Component item data template
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to 'yourtheme/woocommerce/component-item.php'.
 *
 * On occasion, this template file may need to be updated and you (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility.
 * We try to do this as little as possible, but it does happen.
 * When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @version  2.2.0
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
}

?><dl class="component"><?php

 $key = sanitize_text_field( $component_data[ 'key' ] );

 ?><dt class="component-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $key ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $component_data[ 'key' ] ); ?>:</dt>
 <dd class="component-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $key ); ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $component_data[ 'value' ] ) ); ?></dd>
</dl>
```

and the file who contain the code for the mini cart :

```js
 <ul class="mini-products-list" id="cart-sidebar" >
            <?php foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) : ?>
            <?php
               $_product = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
               $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
               
               if ($_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0
                   && apply_filters('woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
               ) :
               
                   $product_name = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_title(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                   $thumbnail = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(array(80, 160)), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                   $product_price = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price($_product), $cart_item, $cart_item_key);
                   $cnt = sizeof(WC()->cart->get_cart());
                   $rowstatus = $cnt % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even';
                   ?>
            <li class="item<?php if ($cnt - 1 == $i) { ?>last<?php } ?>">
              <div class="item-inner">
               <a class="product-image"
                  href="<?php echo esc_url($_product->get_permalink($cart_item)); ?>"  title="<?php echo esc_html($product_name); ?>"> <?php echo str_replace(array('http:', 'https:'), '', htmlspecialchars_decode($thumbnail)); ?> </a>
             

                  <div class="product-details">
                       <div class="access">
                        <a class="btn-edit" title="<?php esc_attr_e('Edit item','bolt') ;?>"
                        href="<?php echo esc_url(WC()->cart->get_cart_url()); ?>"><i
                        class="icon-pencil"></i><span
                        class="hidden"><?php esc_attr_e('Edit item','bolt') ;?></span></a>
                     <a href="<?php echo esc_url(WC()->cart->get_remove_url($cart_item_key)); ?>"
                        title="<?php esc_attr_e('Remove This Item','bolt') ;?>" onClick="" 
                        class="btn-remove1"><?php esc_attr_e('Remove','bolt') ;?></a> 

                         </div>
                      <strong><?php echo esc_html($cart_item['quantity']); ?>
                  </strong> x <span class="price"><?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($product_price); ?></span>
                     <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo esc_url($_product->get_permalink($cart_item)); ?>"
                        title="<?php echo esc_html($product_name); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($product_name); ?></a> </p>
                  </div>
                  <?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode(WC()->cart->get_item_data($cart_item)); ?>
                     </div>
              
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
         </ul>
```

Waiting for your answer to see where I need to change the codes.

Thanks again for your help.

Matt

Comment: Have you contacted Woo support? If it's truly a bug, the author of that plugin is a great developer and usually patches things quickly. But first, have you gone through basic debug process of switching to a default theme and disabling all other plugins, then re-enabling them one by one? Are you overriding those templates in your theme? Are you filtering `woocommerce_cart_item_name` anywhere else?

Comment: Hi Thanks Helgatheviking, but unfortunetly i tried this basic debug and is not working. I tried to do what you wrote me but is not working at all.  Do you think they any problem in the code?

Comment: Basic debug is meant to isolate the problem. So you are saying you have tried using Twenty Seventeen with only WooCommerce and WooCommerce Product Bundles and you still see this error? If so, take screenshots and report to Woo support.